# На одном компьютере при работе с биржей выдает ошибка Invalid nonce, на другом нет

Tags: python

При работе в python с API биржи криптовалют на одном компьютере стала появляться ошибка UNAUTH Invalid nonce. Хотя раньше все работало нормально. Дело не в длительности времени запроса, я считаю, так как интернет связь стабильная, ответ (ошибка) приходит быстро, да и не менялся этот фактор во время первого появления ошибки.

Почему на другом компьютере, в той же интернет сети программа работает, получает необходимые данные с API? С того же аккаунта на бирже, с теми же api key, api secret?

У меня подозрение, что дело в разнице времени на компе с ошибкой, и биржей. Я сверил время на двух компах с помощью функции timr.time() - отличие в 8 секунд. Хотя и там и там время по сети, только Windows разные.

Понятно, что вопрос слишком общий, но я не знаю, из-за чего еще nonce может выдавать ошибку.

Как у меня задан сам этот параметр? Через клиента для этой биржи с сайта github. Лично я не задавал ни nonce, ни шифровку hmac.

Если дело все-таки во времени, прошу подсказать, как написать функцию, что прибавить к времени на моем компе 8 секунд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда комп с "нормальным" временем отправил запрос,  с того компа, где время отстает — запросы идут как бы из прошлого.
Лучше всего синхронизируйте время на обоих компах, не между собой, а NNTP.